# Create slice of pointers using reflection in Go

Tags: reflection, go

I've seen a few examples of reflection around this topic, but I can't find anything that solves this issue. It feels a little convoluted, but the alternative is a massive amount of repetition so I thought I'd give it a try.

I have a function that returns a function (handler). The wrapping function passes in an instance of a struct. I need the inner function to create a slice of pointers to that struct type:

```
func createCollectionHandler(app *appSession, record interface{}, name string) func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    return func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

        // This line needs to be dynamic:
        var result []*Person

        err := meddler.QueryAll(app.MysqlDB, &result, "select * from "+name)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        json, err := json.MarshalIndent(result, "", " ")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        res.Write([]byte(json))
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: That *should* work fine, maybe meddler is doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You can create a slice using reflect and an example of the type like so:

```
var t *MyType

typeOfT := reflect.TypeOf(t)
sliceOfT := reflect.SliceOf(typeOfT)

s := reflect.MakeSlice(sliceOfT, 0, 0).Interface()
```

In order to pass a pointer to the slice without knowing the type, you can create the pointer first, then set the slice value:

```
ptr := reflect.New(sliceOfT)
ptr.Elem().Set(reflect.MakeSlice(sliceOfT, 0, 0))
s := ptr.Interface()
```

http://play.golang.org/p/zGSqe45E60

Comment: @thwd: I know ;) just showing the type assertion in case the OP wasn't sure how to get the concrete type out of the reflect.MakeSlice.

Comment: Hey there. I tried that already, but thought that perhaps I was missing something because I get the following error: ScanAll called with pointer to non-slice: *interface {} which is being emitted from meddler. I'm not married to using meddler, just want a quick and simple way of querying MySQL. I'd happily remove it.

Comment: @i0n: you have to assert the type before you take the address, since you can't use a pointer to an interface. I'll add an example about creating a pointer with reflect if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help! I think what I need to do is create a slice of pointers to a struct type that is passed in through the functions interface. The resulting slice needs to have type slice etc when it is introspected, because I think this is what is causing meddler to blow up. Is this possible?

Comment: @i0n: The first example makes a `[]*MyType`, the second makes a `*[]*MyType`. Those are the actual types which will come out of the interface{}. I think the second example is what you're looking for, since you want the pass the pointer to `meddler.QueryAll` immediately.